# How to generate dynamic quarter numbers with year based on current time stamp in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I've a use case in which I need to get the quarter-wise data used by the users to generate reports.
I'm using MongoDB and I'm getting the data based on quarters and years. Then I need to display the quarters data by comparing with year. But the problem is, am getting duplicate data as Quarter-1 from both years, 2019 & 2020 will gets added. Right now, this is quarter-1 in year 2020. From database, I'll be getting the data based on quarters and years. But I don't have the functionality to compare the years and quarters before displaying them.

As of now I've this functionality to generate the array of quarters and have been doing the comparison of only quarters. Because of this, I'm getting duplicate data.

```js
let quarters = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ].map(i => 
  moment().subtract(i, 'Q').format('[Q]Q')
);

console.log(quarters);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

But my requirement is to get last 3 quarters of previous year too along with current quarter to compare the data I got from the database. For this, I need to have an array like the following.

```
quarters = ['Q2-2019','Q3-2019','Q4-2019','Q1-2020']
```

Is there anyway to generate the year along with quarters dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For retrieving year along with quarter, `format` function of `momentJS` can be used.

Try the below code:

```js
let quarters = [0, 1, 2, 3].map(i => 
  moment().subtract(i, 'Q').format('[Q]Q-Y')
);

console.log(quarters);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```